# linking profile picture on social engine to the correct album ID for profile pictures

Tags: php, smarty, social-networking, socialengine

I'm having a hard time finding any good information on this subject and social engine's support system is....not helping.

I'm trying to edit \application\modules\User\widgets\profile-photo\index.tpl 
file which displays the profile picture on a users's page. it looks like this.

```
<div id='profile_photo'>
<?php echo $this->itemPhoto($this->subject()) ?>
</div>
```

pretty simple. I want to link the photo so that when a viewer clicks the profile picture it will take them to the album that shows all the profile pictures, like facebook kind of. any tips on the right album ID? I tried

```
<a href="/albums/view/<?php echo $album_id; ?>">
```

but that is wrong. I'm just kind of lost and not finding much information online. any help would be great, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have `$album_id` you can use following code to make required URL:

```
$url = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->assemble(
    array(
        'module' => 'album', 
        'controller' => 'album',
        'action' => 'view', 
        'album_id' => $album_id
    ), 
    'default', 
    true
);
```

Comment: Problem is $album_id is wrong. I don't know social engine's api very well and that call doesn't work. What I need help is retrieving the album ID of the profile pictures album, of the person being viewed. not the viewer.

Comment: try to use `getSpecialAlbum($user, 'profile')` method from Album_Model_DbTable_Albums table's model class.

Comment: I get an error "call to undefined function getSpecialAlbum" :(